# javascript implement "select all" check box not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found this code online, and it is okay on Firefox and Chrome, but it doesn't work on IE, do anyone know how to fix it for IE?

the value of the button does toggle, but just the checkbox not able to change

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function do_this(){

        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('approve[]');
        var button = document.getElementById('toggle');

        if(button.value == 'select'){
            for (var i in checkboxes){
                checkboxes[i].checked = 'FALSE';
            }
            button.value = 'deselect'
        }else{
            for (var i in checkboxes){
                checkboxes[i].checked = '';
            }
            button.value = 'select';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="3" />

<input type="button" id="toggle" value="select" onClick="do_this()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you set `checked` is it `'FALSE'` a `string` or `false` a `boolean` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered a best practice to put your handler in code and not in-line.  You can save some code, and put the onclick handler in your code like so:

```
// add event handler
function init() {
    document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function () {
        do_this(this);
    };
}
window.onload = init;

// me is the button here
function do_this(me) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('approve[]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        // toggle to what it is not
        checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
    }
    me.value = me.value == 'select' ? 'deselect' : 'select';
}
```

Sample fiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/qK2qS/

Comment: Just for full disclosure, look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener for information in mondern browsers on event handler attachment (and older IE as well) - special note that "me" in my example will NOT have `this` (the button) from an inline event handler in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a boolean value to the `checked` property. The other browsers are understanding your bizarre logic, and converting `'FALSE'` to the boolean `true` (checking the box), and `''` to `false` (unchecking it)

Use the actual `true` and `false` booleans, and it might just work ;)